# RedisCluster cannot begin from the give arguments

Tags: c++, redis

I have a C++ programm and i need to use the redis++ library instead of hiredis.
i changed my connection to have a redisCluster object, which i create a cluster in my build container and i have the following snippet of code:

```
class DBClient
{
    public:
        DBClient(const Arguments &args): connection_options(), m_redis_client(connection_options) {
         
            m_redis_ip = args.getRedisIP();
            m_redis_port = std::stoi(args.getRedisPort());
          
        }
        ~DBClient();
 
    private:
        std::string  m_redis_ip;
        uint16_t     m_redis_port;
        sw::redis::ConnectionOptions connection_options;
        sw::redis::RedisCluster m_redis_client;
        
};
```

In the cpp i have the following
m_redis_client =  sw::redis::RedisCluster(connection_options);

Then i try to call the DBClient with given arguments for m_redis_ip and m_redis_port in UT

```
std::string arg_redis_ip = "127.0.0.1";
std::string arg_redis_port = "6380";

args.setRedisIP(arg_redis_ip);
args.setRedisPort(arg_redis_port);
DBClient client(args);
```

In this step i get this error
due to unexpected exception with message:
failed to connect to Redis (:6379): Name or service not known

when i change in the hpp the constructor and in the redisCluster object i give a url from the clusters as example
m_redis_client("tcp://27.0.0.1:6380")
i have a success connection.
Can you help me where is the problem and i cannot get in the constructor the correct values?

Then i try to call the DBClient with given arguments for m_redis_ip and m_redis_port in UT

```
std::string arg_redis_ip = "127.0.0.1";
std::string arg_redis_port = "6380";

args.setRedisIP(arg_redis_ip);
args.setRedisPort(arg_redis_port);
DBClient client(args);
```

In this step i get this error
due to unexpected exception with message:
failed to connect to Redis (:6379): Name or service not known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DBClient`'s constructor creates a `RedisCluster` object with a default  constructed `ConnectionOptions`. By default, the host is empty string, and the port is 6379. That's why you get the error message: *failed to connect to Redis (:6379): Name or service not known*.

Although you try to set ip and port, these settings are not set on ConnectionOptions. You can try the following code:

```
class DBClient
{
    public:
        DBClient(const Arguments &args) {
         
            connection_options.host = args.getRedisIP();
            connection_options.port = std::stoi(args.getRedisPort());
            m_redis_client = std::make_unique<sw::redis::RedisCluster>(connection_options);
          
        }
        void set(const string &key, const string &val) {
            m_redis_client->set(key, val);
        }
        ~DBClient();
 
    private:
        sw::redis::ConnectionOptions connection_options;
        std::unique_ptr<sw::redis::RedisCluster> m_redis_client;
        
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. The solution that you provide pass the correct port and host. But from the documentation is not clear that it needs the set function to get the correct values. Thank you